# Firefox not detecting iframe load event?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe

There's an ad unit on my page which is simply an iframe.  When the page loads, there are a couple of different ads that can be displayed within the iframe.  There's a piece of javascript within the iframe that attempts to render the first ad unit with the following method:

```
document.open();
document.write(ad_tag1);
document.close();
```

The first ad unit will render an ad with some probability or else it will fire a postmessage event to the ad unit iframe indicating there's no ad to show.

If there's an ad to show, everything's golden.  However, if there's not, the ad unit will proceed to do:

```
document.open();
document.write(ad_tag2);
document.close();
```

This causes the second ad tag to render just fine.  However, the problem is that Firefox seemingly can't detect when the second ad unit has loaded even though it clearly has and the spinner at the top of the page keeps spinning forever as if there's still stuff to load.

I have also tried using DOM manipulation methods such as innerHTML, but that produced the same problem.  I also tried using Prototype JS's built-in update method, but that also caused the same problems.

Anyone have any ideas why Firefox is doing this?  My code works perfectly on chrome..

Also, I have no control of what the ad tags are.  The ad tags are third party and may as well be black boxes from my point of view as in the ad tags may contain scripts, may drop an iframe, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before, quite a few times.  It is almost always caused by malformed HTML being written to the document, or incomplete HTML.  Consider:

```
<html>
   <div id="myadd2">
       <p>Some stuff<p>
   </div>
```

There is no closing `</p>` and also no closing `<html>` tag.  This can cause Firefox to think the document is still loading.  It won't complete until it receives an EOF from the server (closes connection) or it sees the closing HTML tag and a well formed HTML block.

It might be that the second add contains mismatched quotes, an unterminated html tag or mismatched tags.  Run the HTML content through `xmllint --html` to see what it thinks of it.

Comment: I don't think that's it.  Even doing a document.write on something as simple as:

<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>

causes firefox to load forever.